# Position barlegend in contour plot?

Tags: plotting

How can I have the barlegend positioned above the plot instead of to the right of the plot? I know there is a place command that is given by

```
Plotlegends -> Placed[Automatic,Above],
```

But I don't know how to combine barlegend with placed?

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
 ImageSize -> {400, 300},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 300}],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: **]

Example of when I try to combine BarLegend with Placed

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
 ImageSize -> {400, 300},
 PlotLegends -> {BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 300}], 
   Placed[Automatic, Above]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

As you can see I now have two barlegends with one of them being the same size as the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 300}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {400, 40}, LegendLabel -> "legend", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 10}], Above]]
```

[image]